# Download file on browser using flask API from my s3 bucket with boto3 library

Tags: python-2.7

I want to download file on the browser from the s3 bucket with my flask API. Previously I was storing my data on my server so flask send file worked perfectly for me and I was able to download the file. Now that I have switched to the s3 bucket to store my docs send_file does not work.
I am connecting the s3 server using the boto3 library.

Here is the code for reference

function to download file

```
def download_file_from_s3_bucket(KEY):
    s3_client = s3_bucket_connection()
    try:
        file_obj = open("test.pdf", "r+")
        s3_client.download_fileobj(settings.BUCKET_NAME, KEY, file_obj)
        return file_obj
    except Exception as e:
        return {"status": False, "message": e.message}
```

Flask API:

```
@api.route("/return_file", methods=["GET","POST"])
@jwt_required
def return_file():
    try:
        json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
        upload_id = json_data.get('upload_id')
        upload_path,file_name = v2_business.get_upload_path(upload_id)
        file_link = upload_path

        # old way to get file from local server.
        # return send_file(file_link,file_name)
        download_file_obj = root_business.download_file_from_s3_bucket(upload_path)
        return send_file(download_file_obj, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=file_name)
    except IOError as e:
        return jsonify({"status":  False,
                    "message": (e.__class__.__name__ + ': ' + (str(e)))})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({
            "status": False,
            "message": e.message
        })
```